# Understanding library binding

Tags: c, binding, libraries

I've recently realized that is possible to use a library that is written for a language, on another language by writing a binder for that lib.
What I'm having issues to understand is how a binder is really written. 
Can someone write a short example of binding a C library (just one function to let me able to understand it) to another language ?

Thank you very much

Comment: http://www.swig.org/

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to learn how to do this without using external tools

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a lot on the language and its implementation. Most language implementations document pretty well how to interface C functions to them:

- for C++, it is mostly declaring the called function `extern "C"` (but you need to be careful, e.g. w.r.t. exceptions)
- for [Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/ocaml/index.en.html), read the chapter about [Interfacing C with Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/intfc.html)
- for [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), read the chapter [Programming in C](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Programming-in-C.html#Programming-in-C)
- for [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/), read the [Foreign Function Interface](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Foreign-Function-Interface) section.
- for [CLISP](http://clisp.org/), read its [§32.3. The Foreign Function Call Facility](http://www.clisp.org/impnotes/dffi.html)
- for Python 3, read its [Extending & Embedding the Python Interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html)
- for [MELT](http://gc-melt.org/) (a lispy domain specific language to extend and customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler), there are some tricks and facilities (`code_chunk`-s, `defprimitive`, `defciterator`, `defcmatcher` ...) to make that more easy.
- for [Ruby](http://ruby-lang.org), read about [To Ruby From C and C++](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-cpp/)
- for [Lua](http://lua.org/), read its chapter [4 – The Application Program Interface](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4)
- for [EclipseCLP](http://eclipseclp.org/) (a Prolog dialect), read its [Embedding and Interfacing manual](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/embedding/embroot.html)
- for Java & other [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) based languages (i.e. Clojure or Scala), learn more about [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface)
- for Parrot, read about [Parrot Dynamic C-level Objects](http://docs.parrot.org/parrot/latest/html/docs/book/draft/ch07_dynpmcs.pod.html)
- for Neko, read about [Neko FFI](http://nekovm.org/doc/ffi)
- etc...

Notice that how you should interface depends a lot on the implementation. [Memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) should be a particular concern: many languages have a [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), and you should respect its invariants. Likewise, some language implementations are multithreaded, and you should respect their rules related to threads. Several implementations are demanding some particular C interface for adding your new primitives, others are more flexible. Some implementations are permitting callbacks (i.e. language function calling your C primitive which call back some language function), but others don't.

Notice also that two different implementations of the *same* language (e.g. both CLISP and SBCL are [Common Lisp](http://common-lisp.net/) implementations) have different (and usually *incompatible*) ways of interfacing to C.

As [Oliver Chalesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129570/oliver-charlesworth) commented, you might look inside [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) which may generate some glue code for you.

My feeling is that the most important thing is to understand the constraints of the garbage collector used by the language. You may (or not) want to use its [finalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalization) facilities (e.g. should a file handle or database handle be implicitly closed by finalization inside the GC, or explicitly by some function called by the user?). You probably want to read the [Garbage Collection Handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) to get an overview of different GC techniques.

The GTK library has a lot of [language bindings](http://www.gtk.org/language-bindings.php) and its [GObjectIntrospection](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GObjectIntrospection) layer claim to facilitate language bindings. You might also be interested by [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/) (at least if you are implementing some language).

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've a better idea on how this works.. PS: just can't undestand why there is always someone that downvote these questions...

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but since it is not related to your source code, it could be considered as slightly off-topic and might be more suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Damn I wasn't aware of that. In the future I'll use that site for anything related to programming but not directly related to code.